# How to install Node.Js via Source Code in Ubuntu 16.04 Server?

Tags: node.js, installation, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

Some of yours facing issue with installing the latest version of NodeJs on Ubuntu 16.04 Server?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no "installation" per se, you just need to extract the tarball, and make sure the node and npm binaries in the ./bin subdirectory are somewhere in your path.

I find nvm is useful for managing node installations (it will download, extract, and add to path for you). If you want to do things manually, you can do something like:

```
wget https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.5.0/node-v10.5.0-linux-x64.tar.gz

tar -xvf node-v6.9.2-linux-x64.tar.gz --directory /usr/local --strip-components 1
```

This will put the ./bin directory in /usr/local/bin, which should be in your $PATH already. You can verify that it worked with:

```
node --version

npm --version
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When using nvm, nodenv or chnode, the installation usually goes into a hidden directory under $HOME. To install a Node version manually for use with chnode, the `tar` command would become: `tar -xvf node-v10.5.0-linux-x64.tar.gz --directory ~/.nodes/node-10.5.0 --strip-components 1`

Comment: Just a curious off topic question - isn't all installation extracting stuff?

Answer (score 0):

[How To Install Node.js on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04) has some useful guidance for installing, node, npm and nvm.